# How do I prevent users from entering values that exceed TSpinEdit.MaxValue?

Tags: delphi

I set the MaxValue of a TSpinEdit to 100000 but when I run the program it lets me enter values over 100000 if I enter it manually (instead of using the spins).
There is any way to limit the value to MaxValue without writing code? Otherwise the MaxValue property is 100% useless.

The problem is that when the user enters a huge value this gives an RageCheckError because BigFileThreshis Cardinal.

```
procedure TFrmMain.spnMaxFileSizeChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
 PlaylistCtrl.BigFileThresh:= spnMaxFileSize.Value * KB;
end;
```

This new behavior of TSpinEdit **can cause Delphi programs to crash in many places**. I liked the one from Delphi 7 better.

It would be easy for THE CURRENT situation to add a line like:

```
 if spnMaxFileSize.Value> spnMaxFileSize.MaxValue  
 then spnMaxFileSize.Value:= spnMaxFileSize.MaxValue;
```

But to add this line from now on or to open all my programs and add this line? This is crazy!

Comment: @TLama - I updated the question. You will see the problem now.

Comment: I don't see how it's 100% useless. It still prevents the number from going too high when using the spin buttons, doesn't it?

Comment: Ok. Is 50% useless because 50% of users (maybe more?) will enter the value manually.

Comment: Can't you just check the value in the OnChange event, and only use it if it's within the allowed range? It takes one line of code, and I don't see why a programmer should be averse to writing code.

Comment: So which Delphi version has this problem?

Comment: @Roddy - Delphi XE has it. I guess is like this since Delphi 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solution:

```
TYPE
 TMySpinEdit = class(TSpinEdit)   { Fixes the OnChange MinValue/MaxValue issue }
  private
   Timer: TTimer;
   FOnChanged: TNotifyEvent;
   procedure TimesUp(Sender: TObject);
  public
   constructor Create (AOwner: TComponent);override;
   destructor Destroy;override;
   procedure Change; override;
  published
   property OnChanged: TNotifyEvent read FOnChanged write FOnChanged;
 end;

constructor TMySpinEdit.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
 inherited;
 Timer:= TTimer.Create(Self);
 Timer.OnTimer:= TimesUp;
 Timer.Interval:= 2500; { allow user 2.5 seconds to enter a new correct value }
end;

destructor TMySpinEdit.Destroy;
begin
 FreeAndNil(Timer);
 inherited;
end;

procedure TMySpinEdit.Change;
begin
 Timer.Enabled:= FALSE;
 Timer.Enabled:= TRUE;
end;

procedure TMySpinEdit.TimesUp;
begin
 Timer.Enabled:= FALSE;
 if (MaxValue<> 0) AND (Value> MaxValue) then Value:= MaxValue;
 if (MinValue<> 0) AND (Value< MinValue) then Value:= MinValue;
 if Assigned(FOnChanged) then FOnChanged(Self);
end;
```

Code not tested yet (to be compiled).

---

The other solution would be:

```
TYPE
 TMySpinEdit = class(TSpinEdit)
  public
   procedure Change; override;
 end;

IMPLEMENTATION

procedure TMySpinEdit .Change;
begin
 if (Value > MaxValue) OR (Value < MinValue) then
  begin
    Color:= clRed;
    EXIT;  { Out of range value. Don't trigger the OnChange event. }
  end;

 Color:= clWindow;
 inherited;
end;
```

Comment: well... after working for a while with RxSpinEdit (now part of http://jvcl.sf.net ) i can say you that is not useless, but a dangerous and destructive.

Imaging the MAX is set on 20000 and entereg value is 10000. User wants to change it to 10500 - a legal choice. He puts the curson in the middle of text and types "5". Then he types "Del" to delete an extra zero char. And then he finds himself in front of an EMPTY edt box, because when he typed "5" overzealous OnChange killed his input and replaced with new, all-selected "20000" text.

The problem "when to digitize the value" is not easy.

Comment: you may try to do it when loosing the focus, for example. or when something reads from `TSpinEdit.AsInteger` or from `TSpinEdit.AsFloat`. But you definitaly should not ruin user's data by removing his input in the middle of it via `OnChange` event.

Comment: If you want it to resove this way you should not forget to add override to your `procedure Change;` and call `inherited` at the end of your procedure.

Comment: Why do you think you need your own OnChange event? Can't you just override `Change` instead, and do your new work there? That method will call the class's OnChange event already.

Comment: @Arioch'The - I see your point and agree with it, BUT, I wouldn't call it (not even by far) destructive! If the user wanted to enter 10500 and value was "erased' during editing, he can start over. He had the number 10500 in his mind 2 seconds ago, he still has the number in his mind now. Nothing was destroyed or lost. Anyway, I updated my post and I propose an alternative. More user friendly.

Comment: That is if the number like 10500 is simple and well-known to user. But imagine a number like 32768. I keyed it from memory, and probably so would you - but laymen would not remember it after one second glance. There might be some similarly non-trivial number coming from some physics or like that. User wants to just change the scale or change the sign, and then oooops!  And real user-friendly approach would be to design the form using things like `TJvValidators`, and not ever "prevent user from entering" garbage into editboxes, but instead give them clear warnings and quick-fixes

Comment: @Arioch'The - If the user wants to enter 32768 then it knows the number. Right?

Comment: IF he wants, but he does NOT want, he wants just to increase (or decrease) number tenfold without knowing what the number was already in the edit box. There were some crazy defaults, or maybe he entered those numbers year ago. Now he wants to adjust them, he does not remember them or their meaning. You can say he MUST memorize it and make a photo, and maybe even have his lawyer notarize that photo. It is doable, but annoying verily. So i believe except for maybe 1% niche cases if user inserts or removes one character the editbox has zero rights to change any other symbol.

Comment: Especially so as when user is keying in he is probably looking on his real or virtual keyboard, and NOT onto the screen, and he does not even see the editbox tampering his year-long data

Comment: At this point is the old number that rellevant? He know that 500 was too small, now he want to enter something like 10x higher. So he just enters 5000. It doesn't matter what was on screen. Now he is totally focused on entering his new number (5000) into the program.  The 500 was lost during editing. So what? He WANTS to enter a VERY different number anyway. The whole idea is that once he decided that the old number is too small, he already has the new number in his mind. HE MADE A DECISION about that the new value will be.

Answer (score 2):

As you've found, the SpinEdit's "onChange" event will be called, even if the currently entered number is outside the range. When you change focus to a different control, the value gets 
limited correctly.

You could try making a new (derived) version of TSpinEdit which doesn't work this way, oryou can just add the required checking to your OnChange event handler.

Comment: @roddy - Thanks Roddy, I am working on a version with timer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Since the only place checkvalue is called is the message handler of CM_Exit you could use

```
procedure TFrmMain.spnMaxFileSizeChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
 SendMessage(TSpinEdit(Sender).Handle,CM_EXIT,0,0);
 PlaylistCtrl.BigFileThresh:= spnMaxFileSize.Value * KB;
end;
```

to recieve the desired behavior.

investigate ..\source\Win32\Samples\Source.

Comment: The idea is that: 1) one will forget to add this line every time it ads a f*cking TSpinEdit on the form. 2) one will have to fix it in all existing code. Doing a batch replace for TSpinEdit with TGoodSpinEdit will be easier (automatic).

Comment: Plus that this code introduces other functionality problems. Anyway, good to keep in mind also this solution. +1